# Unpacking argument lists for ellipsis in R

Tags: list, r, ellipsis, iterable-unpacking

I am confused by the use of the ellipsis (`...`) in some functions, i.e. how to pass an object containing the arguments as a single argument.

In Python it is called "unpacking argument lists", e.g.

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

In R for instance you have the function `file.path(...)` that uses an ellipsis. I would like to have this behaviour:

```
> args <- c('baz', 'foob') 
> file.path('/foo/bar/', args)
[1] 'foo/bar/baz/foob'
```

Instead, I get

```
[1] 'foo/bar/baz' 'foo/bar/foob'
```

where the elements of `args` are not "unpacked" and evaluated at the same time. Is there a R equivalent to Pythons `*arg`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The syntax is not as beautiful, but this does the trick:

```
do.call(file.path,as.list(c("/foo/bar",args)))
```

`do.call` takes two arguments: a function and a list of arguments to call that function with.

Comment: An extended discussion on this technique: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-new-r-trick-for-me-at-least/

Comment: ...and another explanation, also from R Bloggers, which helped me a lot: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/09/breaking-the-ellipsis/

Answer (score 24):

You can extract information from the ellipsis by calling `list(...)` inside the function. In this case, the info in the ellipsis is packaged as a list object. For example:

```
> foo <- function(x,...){
+   print(list(...))
+ }
> foo(1:10,bar = 'bar','foobar')
$bar
[1] "bar"

[[2]]
[1] "foobar"
```

You can achieve the desired behaviour from vectorised functions like `file.path` with a call to `do.call`, which is sometimes simpler to use with the wrapper `splat` (in the `plyr` package)

```
> args <- c('baz', 'foob')
> library(plyr)
> splat(file.path)(c('/foo/bar', args))
[1] "/foo/bar/baz/foob"
```

Answer (score 10):

It took me a while to find it, but the [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package has an equivalent to [`plyr::splat`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/splat): it's called [`lift_dl`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html).

The "dl" in the name stands for "dots to list", as it's part of a series of `lift_xy` functions that can be used to "lift" the domain of a function from one kind of input to another kind, these "kinds" being lists, vectors and "dots".

Since `lift_dl` is probably the most useful of those, there is a simple `lift` alias provided for it.

To reuse the above example:

```
library(purrr)
args <- c("baz", "foob")
lift(file.path)(c("/foo/bar", args))
# [1] "/foo/bar/baz/foob"
```

## Update

As of purrr 1.0.0, [the `lift_*` family of functions is deprecated](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#purrr-100).

Moving forward, one should instead use [`rlang::inject`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/inject.html) to enable splicing via the [`!!!` operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html):

```r
library(rlang)
args <- c("baz", "foob")
inject(file.path("/foo/bar", !!!args))
#> [1] "/foo/bar/baz/foob"
```

Comment: This is brilliant!