# Switch Statements in R (Unpacking Arguments)

Tags: r

Google search doesn't return much on this. How do you unpack arguments in R?

For instance if I try to use switch in R like

```
switch("AA",c("AA"=5,"BB"=6))
```

I will get back `c("AA"=5,"BB"=6)` when in reality, I want 5.

Essentially, I want to be able to do `switch("AA","AA"=5,"BB"=6)` with a vector mapping.

Comment: My apologies, I want 5 :)

Comment: @user1431282 What do you mean by unpacking arguments. Does this in the python sense ?

Comment: @agstudy I think he thinks about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414078/unpacking-argument-lists-for-ellipsis-in-r?rq=1

Comment: @Qbik thanks. It is the Python sense of the term.( as it is confirmed in the link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a workaround, but try:

```
do.call("switch", append(list("AA"), list("AA"=5, "BB"=6)))
```

The `do.call()` allows you to pass a list of arguments into `switch()`.

Comment: +1 - or `do.call(switch, as.list(c(EXPR = "AA", c("AA"= 5,"BB"= 6))))`

Comment: Couldn't this be simplified to `do.call("switch", append("AA", list("AA"=5, "BB"=6)))`. What does the `list("AA")` do?

Comment: @Thomas It can be shortened as you suggest. The `list("AA")` was to insure that there wasn't any type coercion to go wrong. Your shortened version is converting a one element character vector to a one element list before appending the other list.

Answer (score 3):

This is how `switch` was intended to be used. The first argument gets evaluated and match to the first elements of the succeeding pairlists:

```
 aa <- "AA"
 switch(aa,"AA"=5,"BB"=6)
#[1] 5
 switch("BB","AA"=5,"BB"=6)
#[1] 6
```

At least that is the strategy for 'character' arguments. The process for numeric arguments is different. One needs to read the Details section of `?switch` carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is rather short, mayby you could obtain demanded functionality this way :

```
my.vector = c("AA"=5,"BB"=6)
my.vector[names(my.vector ) == "AA"]

AA 
 5
```

?

Answer (score 2):

```
> c("AA"=5,"BB"=6)["AA"]
AA 
 5 
> c("AA"=5,"BB"=6)["BB"]
BB 
 6
```