# Passing list of characters into file.path in R

Tags: r, file, directory, path, parent

I want to get the parent directory from a folder path.

say I have: "C:/Users/YS/2020 projects/APP/pect/PDC/src"

and I want to get: "C:/Users/YS/2020 projects/APP/pect/PDC"

```
#Get current directory
cpath = getwd()

#Remove last folder from path
dir <- strsplit(cpath,"/")
dir <- dir[[1]]
parent_dir <- dir[1:length(dir)-1]

#Return file path
file.path(parent_dir)
```

These are my environment variables:

[image]

and here is the output I get from the code:

```
[1] "C:"            "Users"         "YS"            "2020 projects" "APP"           "pect"          "PDC"
```

I want it to return:

```
[1] "C:/Users/YS/2020 projects/APP/pect/PDC"
```

Why can't I pass a list of characters into file.path()?

I'm a little confused by how dir in my environment variables is listed as a character not a list or vector

I'm also a little confused by why strsplit returns a list with 1 value in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to remove the "src", an option is `sub`

```
sub("[/][a-z]+$", "", cpath)
```

---

If we want to use `file.path`, where the usage is

> file.path(..., fsep = .Platform$file.sep)

The `...` implies multiple arguments passed one by one, i.e.

```
file.path(parent_dir[1], parent_dir[2])
#[1] "C:/Users"
```

and so on

```
parent_dir
#[1] "C:"            "Users"         "YS"            "2020 projects" "APP"           "pect"          "PDC"
```

If we want to replicate that, an option is to place it in a `list` and use `file.path` with `do.call`

```
do.call(file.path, as.list(parent_dir))
#[1] "C:/Users/YS/2020 projects/APP/pect/PDC"
```

Or with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(file.path, as.list(parent_dir))
#[1] "C:/Users/YS/2020 projects/APP/pect/PDC"
```

Comment: My main question is, how can I feed a list of strings into file.path?

Comment: In case you are interested in the answer, your main question I tried to answer

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for do.call

My question wasn't very well worded, what I was looking for was a way to unpack arguments from a list like in python. I found a similar question/response here on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414078/unpacking-argument-lists-for-ellipsis-in-r

Comment: In `R`, there is no `*` or `**` for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

With an array being passed as the input it is applying the function to each element separately.  It might be necessary to use `paste` with the array.

```
paste(parent_dir, collapse = "/")
```

Another approach that may be simpler:

```
dirname(getwd())
```

The reason that `strsplit` returns a list is that it can handle multiple inputs:

```
 users <- c("c:/users/A", "c:/users/B")
 strsplit(users, "/")

[[1]]
[1] "c:"    "users" "A"    

[[2]]
[1] "c:"    "users" "B"
```

For the environment, `dir` is a character `array` with eight elements.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. I was looking for a command like dirname()