# rowwise() sum with vector of column names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am once again confused about how to achieve this:

Given this data frame:

```
df <- tibble(
  foo = c(1,0,1),
  bar = c(1,1,1),
  foobar = c(0,1,1)
)
```

And this vector:

```
to_sum <- c("foo", "bar")
```

I would like to get the row-wise sum of the values in the columns `to_sum`.

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise: 
    foo   bar foobar   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1      0     2
2     0     1      1     1
3     1     1      1     2
```

Typing it out works (obviously).

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = sum(foo, bar)
  )
```

This does not:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = sum(to_sum)
  )
```

Which I understand, because if I were to try:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = sum("foo", "bar")
  )
```

How can I compute the row-wise sum from a vector of column names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rlang::syms` to coerce strings to quosures:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = sum(!!!syms(to_sum))
  )
#     foo   bar foobar   sum
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1      0     2
# 2     0     1      1     1
# 3     1     1      1     2
```

Comment: concise and elegant.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I tried it with `!!syms()` and forgot that I should tripple "unbang" it.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(janitor)
df %>%
  adorn_totals("col",,,"sum",to_sum)

 foo bar foobar sum
   1   1      0   2
   0   1      1   1
   1   1      1   2
```

**Why `,,,` ?**

If you look at `?adorn_totals`, you'll see its arguments:

`adorn_totals(dat, where = "row", fill = "-", na.rm = TRUE, name = "Total", ...)`

The final one `...` is to control column selection.  There's unfortunately no way to tell R directly that `to_sum` should be used for that `...` argument, so the `,,,` in this answer is telling it to use the default values for the arguments `where`, `fill,` and `na.rm`.  At that point, it has values for every argument besides `...`, so `to_sum` gets applied to that.

The topic is discussed further here: [Specify the dots argument when calling a tidyselect-using function without needing to specify the preceding arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760245/specify-the-dots-argument-when-calling-a-tidyselect-using-function-without-needi)

Comment: Nice! I wasn't familiar with this `,,,` technique. Could you please explain a bit more about this.

Comment: Yes, I've just added more to the answer explaining it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was not aware of your `janitor` package. I will certainly look into it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `c_across` and `any_of`. This is how it is intended to be used by the RStudio Team: check out `vignette("rowwise", package = "dplyr")`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(any_of(to_sum))))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     foo   bar foobar   sum
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1      0     2
#> 2     0     1      1     1
#> 3     1     1      1     2
```

`c_across` is specific for rowwise operations.
`any_of` is needed to interpret `to_sum` as a character vector containing column names. It works even without it but it is usually preferred to be used.

You may want to `ungroup()` at the end to remove the `rowwise`.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

df %>%
  bind_cols(parse_exprs(to_sum) %>%
              map_dfc(~ eval_tidy(.x, data = df)) %>%
              rowSums()) %>%
  rename(sum = ...4)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    foo   bar foobar   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1      0     2
2     0     1      1     1
3     1     1      1     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using `rowSums`:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(sum = rowSums(across(all_of(to_sum))))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    foo   bar foobar   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1      0     2
2     0     1      1     1
3     1     1      1     2
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed. I accepted the `!!!syms()` solution, but I like that this does not need the `rowwise()` function. Thanks